# How ssl collision finder works?

Tags: ssl, certificate, md5, collision, sha

I was studying md5 ssl collision vulnerability and can't solve some questions.

If md5 ssl became vulnerable why there is still Thawte certificate signed by md5 in browsers?

And also, how does ssl collision finding algorythm works? Is it the same as finding md5/sha hash collision, or it's just a part of it? I am confused because of two files: key and cert.

My thoughts:
We are creating key file with text "a", then sign certificate with this key and check md5 sum if it equals needed md5 sum. Then change "a" to "b". But it seems to be bruteforce, not collision finding. Is it correct?